# java.io.FileNotFoundException:<path to file>/document.xml (The parameter is incorrect)

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

I have following code

**code:**

```
...

FileOutputStream outputStreams = new FileOutputStream(xmlFile);// Exception occurs from this line
OutputFormat outputFormat = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();
XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(outputStreams, outputFormat);
writer.write(document);

...
```

When I run above code from eclipse then code works well but when I create runnable jar file it gives following exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\6.OutPut\Doc-2018-05-22-15-33.xml (The parameter is incorrect)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bipro.EncodeBase64.operation.EncodeOperation.encodeAndCompressGZ(EncodeOperation.java:89)
```

I have searched for solution in stackoverflow but can not find any solution.

Comment: Are you sure the value of `xmlFile` isn't "D:\6.OutPut\Doc-2018-05-22-15-33.xml (The parameter is incorrect)" ?

Comment: Nevermind, found a duplicate

Comment: could not understood. Can you please tell me clearly? @Aaron

Comment: I was wondering if "(The parameter is incorrect)" wasn't part of the filename you passed to `new FileOutputStream`, but it looks like this is a known bug, so I've linked a previous question about this topic

Comment: Is there any alternative solution for that? @Aaron

Comment: take a look to  https://www.baeldung.com/java-classpath-resource-cannot-be-opened